# Can we filter HNQ by ignored tags?

Tags: feature-request

Following scenario: I have ignored the tag (don't show questions at all) [game-of-thrones](/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) on [scifi.stackexchange.com](https://scifi.stackexchange.com). Yet on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com), I am still shown all HNQ which are tagged with [game-of-thrones](/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones). The same example works for [movies.stackexchange.com](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

I find this behaviour quite odd, as I explicitly set exactly those questions not to be shown to me to avoid any possible spoilers in the titles (happens quite often).

Therefore I would like to propose to filter HNQ by the ignored tags per site. What I mean with that is, that if I ignore the tag [game-of-thrones](/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) on movie.se, I don't want to see any of those questions in HNQ, but only the ones coming from movie.se. Questions tagged [game-of-thrones](/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) from scifi.se should still be shown, as I don't ignore the tag on that site.

---

I hope this is understandable. If you need some clarification let me know and I will try to provide it.

I couldn't find any duplicate to this question, but if it has already been proposed, please let me know.

Comment: @Anne duplicate, not just relevant. Exact same request.